# How to find order of Jacobson Radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, gap

Is there any method to find order of Jacobson Radical  of any ring that is non semi simple? Actually i have to find order of Jacobson radical of Group algebra $F_{3^n}(GL_2(Z_3))$. Is there any way by using GAP. Please help me.. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the $n$? At first I thought you just meant the group algebra for $GL_2(Z_3)$ over $F_3$, but then I couldn't make sense of the $n$. Do you mean to ask about $F_{3^n}$ in general?

Comment: Yes exactly ....it's for order of field...

Comment: I edited it...thanks...

Comment: If you type in GAP `??Radical` with two question marks, it returns a list of all help sections containing substring `Radical` - that would lead you to  `RadicalOfAlgebra` as suggested by @ahulpke. This is a very time-saving way to search in GAP documentation, it should be tried before trying other search methods.

Comment: Thanks ..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume (as in your examples) that the ring is in fact an algebra. Since the Jacobson radical is the maximal nilpotent ideal, you can use `RadicalOfAlgebra`, i.e.

RadicalOfAlgebra(GroupRing(GF(3),GL(2,3)));

In the example the codimension 28 agrees with the degrees (1,1,2,2,3,3) of the Brauer characters.

Comment: thanks a lot sir....

Comment: I tried for $GF(9)$ it’s also comes 28 .... how can I say about $GL(3^n)$ in general ?

Comment: How you find it’s Brauer character ...

Comment: @neelkanth that is a completely different question.

Comment: Thanks sir ....I will ask it in different  way....thanku....

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659756/please-tell-the-mistake-in-gap-computation